# Tratar valores nulos

Tags: python

Tengo que tratar una columna llamada `Peso` que es de tipo `objetct` y la tengo que devolver como columna tipo `float64`, pero debe mantener los valores nulos que mantenía en el momento de entrar en la función.

Tengo tres pasos para intentar hacer esto que me piden y me falta el último, que no sé como sustituir el valor `-1` a valor `NaN`.

1- Como `Peso` y `altura` no pueden ser negativos rellena los nulos con datos `-1`
2- Después pasa toda la columna al tipo correspondiente
3- Filtra para seleccionar los valores negativos y asigna el valor nulo (`numpy.nan` o `np.nan`)

```
def extraer_peso(df):
    df['Peso'].fillna("-1", inplace=True)
    df['Peso'] = df['Peso'].apply(lambda x: int(x[0:2]))
    assert(isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame))
    return df

extraer_peso(df)
```

No sé cual es el tercer paso, porque de este modo me cambia los nulos a `-1`, pero los necesito en `NaN`.

Comment: y no es más sencillo directamente forzar a convertir esa columna a valores numéricos? De ese modo los que no sean convertibles ya quedarán con el valor NaN, evitándote el paso intermedio por el -1. Bastaría hacer `df.Peso = pd.to_numeric(df.Peso, errors="coerce")`

Comment: En todo caso, lo que tú pides en el tercer paso (convertir -1 en Nan)  se haría así: `df.Peso[df.Peso==-1] = float("nan")`

Comment: Me ha cambiado! ha funcionado, gracias, aunque me sale un mensaje como este: <ipython-input-6-a43acfb966ec>:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame